# Могу ли я удалять ненужные мне компоненты из пакета gnome?

Tags: linux, archlinux, gnome, desktop, x86-64

Могу ли я удалять ненужные компоненты из gnome (gnome-remote, например), повлияет ли это на работу системы?
И что нужно сделать помещать ярлыки на рабочий стол (они не помещаются, правой кнопкой мышки только три пункта)
Есть ли какой-то пакет для быстрой "адаптации" gnome? (Быстрая настройка)
Arch x64 (BIOS, Not UEFI)
Gnome 3.30.2

Answer (score 0):

По порядку:

1. Да, можете - это не проблема.
2. Все зависит от того, какой именно пакет, в первую очередь надо смотреть какие пакеты зависят от того, который вы хотите удалить. Поэтому - да, может сломать, а может вообще ничего не будет.
3. Нет, обычно это делается скриптами и какждый раз под себя.

Comment: А не могли бы вы дать ссылку на сырой скрипт (форму), ну или просто готовый с какого-либо источника скинуть?

Comment: @DaniilShilo Ключевые слова - каждый делает сам под себя. Соответственно и скрипты держат обычно локально. На каких-то форумах в интернете можно найти только кусочки, как что-то кастомизировать. Но я бы вам не советовал их вообще трогать с учетом того, что вы не сильны с gnome.

Comment: @DaniilShilo Еще дело в том, что понятие адаптация - это очень-очень размытый термин. Поэтому на эту часть почти невозможно ответить, чтобы не начался холивар.

Comment: Я понимаю, просто недавно только перешёл с семёрки на арч, вроде бы все работает, то что не работало пофиксил, и остался только этот стол. Написал на стак, ибо нигде нет ответов, на английском стаке тоже подобного не находил. Теперь сижу думаю. Позвольте задать ещё один вопрос, в твикере, как я понял должна быть вкладка Desktop, однако у меня её нет, её тоже можно включить с помощью конфига?

Comment: @DaniilShilo Я не смогу вам ответить на это, потому что я не пользуюсь gnome уже давно и не использую Arch. Я работаю в Mint + Cinnamon, а основная система Mac OS.